# cookie didn't destroy straight away, cookie disappear after 1 minute

Tags: php, cookies

I have set up `if no session OR cookie`, the page will header to index. The session destroy works fine, however cookie has the problem.

When I destroy cookie(log out), the page didn't head to index straight away, have to wait for 1 min. The cookie is gone after 1 minute. Anyone know where is the problem.

```
setcookie('id', $id, time()+60, "/");

function destroySession() {
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
    } 
    session_destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a cookie with the name `id` and trying to unset a cookie which name is the result of `session_name()`. That will work if `session_name()` happens to return `id` but not if it returns something else.

I would use `session_name()` to set the cookie:

```
$id = session_id();
setcookie(session_name(), $id, time()+60, "/");
```

Also note that it's probably best to use the [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) for all parameters. The cookie is set automatically when you call `session_start()`